# Passing latitude and longitude as parameters in url

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create an html file to show google maps. Here is the code I am using to accomplish it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Map</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map-container" class="col-md-6"></div>


    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script>    



  function init_map() {

    var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(12.989802,80.2487);

    var var_mapoptions = {
      center: var_location,
      zoom: 14
    };

    var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: var_location,
        map: var_map,
        title:"Venice"});

    var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
        var_mapoptions);

    var_marker.setMap(var_map); 

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);

   </script>
  </body>
```

In this code the values and latitude and longitude are manually given inside the js. But i want that latitude and longitude to be passed as url parameters.

EX : http://www.smart.com/3.html?q=12.989802,80.2487

This is because my url will be called from an app and they want to pass latitude and longitude as a parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write code to read and parse the query string.  One description of how to do that is [Part 20 Passing and receiving parameters](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/linktothis.htm) of Mike Williams' Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial (note that v2 is deprecated and turned off, but the same principles apply to v3).

[example using "q=40.7127837,-74.0059413" (the code snippet doesn't take query parameters)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_coordsFromQuery.html?q=40.7127837,-74.0059413)

```js
function init_map() {
  var lat, lng;
  // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
  // looking something like  "?q=42,-72"

  // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
  var query = location.search.substring(1);

  // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
  var pairs = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1).toLowerCase();

    // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
    if (argname == "q") {
      var coords = value.split(",");
      lat = parseFloat(coords[0]);
      lng = parseFloat(coords[1]);
    }
  }
  var var_location;
  if (isNaN(lat) || isNaN(lng)) {
    var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(12.989802, 80.2487);
  } else {
    var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  }
  var var_mapoptions = {
    center: var_location,
    zoom: 14
  };

  var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: var_location,
    map: var_map,
    title: "Venice"
  });

  var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
    var_mapoptions);

  var_marker.setMap(var_map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-container" class="col-md-6"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your function. Try this.

```
function init_map() {
    var urlParams = /\?q=([^,]+),([^,]+)/.exec(window.location.search), 
            var_location;

    if (urlParams) {
        var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(urlParams[1]), parseFloat(urlParams[2]));
    } else {
        return;
    }


    var var_mapoptions = {
        center: var_location,
        zoom: 14
    };

    var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: var_location,
        map: var_map,
        title: "Venice"
    });

    var var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
            var_mapoptions);

    var_marker.setMap(var_map);

}
```

Is this the behaviour you want? Just bear in the mind. If there are no required parameters in the url function will do nothing. Make sure to put any default or doing anything else. Good luck in implementation.